# How to add a custom type of currency and its value in Corda?

Tags: corda

I want to add a custom type of currency in Corda. How do I do this?

For example: I want to introduce a currency called "egy" whose value is 1egy=2$.

Answer (score 3):

To create a new token, you can use the [TokenSDK](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk) to help.
The following lines create a new token.

```
TokenType myTokenType = new TokenType("MyCoin", 4);
IssuedTokenType issuingToken = new IssuedTokenType(coinIssuer, myTokenType);
```

For the rest, you can use the built-in IssueTokens to help.

```
Amount<IssuedTokenType> issueAmount = new Amount(100, issuingToken);
FungibleToken myToken = new FungibleToken(issueAmount, receivingParty, null);
SignedTransaction stx = subFlow(new IssueTokens(ImmutableList.of(myToken), observers));
```

However, you will have to declare the linkage between other tokens yourself.